# Merge fields for HTML5 attributes of Visualforce tags

Tags: visualforce, html5, merge-field

Is it possible to include merge fields for custom HTML attributes of Visualforce tags? The following code doesn't seem to work.

```
<apex:repeat value="{!lst_items}" var="item">
   <apex:inputText value="{!item.Value}" html-data-object="{!item.objectName}" />
</apex:repeat>
```

The above code throws the following compilation error:

> Unknown property : Classname.item

The item property is declared public with getters and setters. In fact, the following works fine.

```
<apex:repeat value="{!lst_items}" var="item">
   {!item.objectName}
</apex:repeat>
```

Answer (score 2):

No it is not possible. As per Salesforce documentation.

> Pass-through attributes aren’t supported in dynamic Visualforce.

I also tried and it is only working for static values.

Source - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_html_features_pass_through_attributes.htm

Comment: Well that's awfully lame... Any idea if HTML-passthroughs are supported by Dynamic VF Components? If so, you could probably accomplish the same

Comment: I am not using dynamic visualforce component but using merge fields in static markup. Isn't dynamic visualforce is something you create using apex? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_dynamic_vf_components_intro.htm

Comment: @user5050 What I meant to say was if you write html-data-object="xyz" it will work but if you write html-data-object="{!item.objectName}" it won't as the value is dynamic.